# Running php multithreaded(using pthread) script from wamp localhost on Windows

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, wamp

am trying to execute a multithreaded php script using php pthreads on Windows.

I have followed the following links, and placed the following files

pthreadVC2.dll

php_pthreads.dll

as suggested by the following links
http://emrahmehmedov.blogspot.com/2013/03/php-and-multi-thread-on-windows.html
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Also I have made changes to the php.ini file, as suggested.

The problem is :

The script is executed well when run using 'php' command using windows commandline, but when I try to run it from wamp-server localhost(wamp/www/)
from the browser , it gives error "Thread Class not found".

Any Idea Why is this happening?? Any Solution for this?? as I have to run the script from the wamp-server localhost through browser. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the pthreads module in the browser with WAMP Server you need to copy the "pthreadVC2.dll" into the apache "bin" directory also.

You should now have he "pthreadVC2.dll" in both of these folders (if installed in default location):

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php[x.x.xx]\bin
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache[x.x.x]\bin
```

You will also need to update the php.ini file within the php bin directory and the apache bin directory to include:

```
extension=php_pthreads.dll
```